# Parse.com not saving ParseObjects

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to upload file to Parse cloud.

```
final ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("somefile.png", data);
    parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){

                ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("photo");
                parseObject.setObjectId("someId");
                parseObject.put("photo1", parseFile);
                parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e==null){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Save done");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "ex" + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Log.d("USER", "file save ex" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

This will run and show successfully and show "Save done" log. But when i go to Parse dashboard i don't see anything changing in data.
I tried to retrieve object:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("photo");
    query.getInBackground("someId", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                Log.d("USER", "OK");
            } else {
                Log.d("USER", "ex" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

But i get ParseException: `no results found for query`.

Comment: do you are setting the Id?

Comment: yes, the parseObject id, here: `parseObject.setObjectId("someId");`. Anyway (if that failed from some reason) the Parse would generate id for me, and I should still be able at least see that class on dashboard, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are saving the parseFile twice and forgetting to save the parse object that you placed the file in.

change this

```
parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e==null){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Save done");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "ex" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
```

to this

```
parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e==null){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Save done");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "ex" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I tried that. You can see that inside `parseFile.saveInBackground(...)` I am doing `parseObject.saveInBackground`. I tried saving `parseObject` only (did not work), and then tried chaining file and object, and from some reason i pasted that chained version code.

Comment: @Gudin Nowhere in your code you have posted do you save your ParseObject. Inside your `parseFile.saveInBackground()` you have another `parseFile.saveInBackground()`  If this is not the correct code that you are having problems with then please update your post with the correct code.

Comment: Damn I'm so blind. Autocomplete got me there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes its always the small things that cause the most problems. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would to do something like this:

```
// Create the ParseFile
ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("somefile.png", data);
file.saveInBackground();

ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("photo");
imgupload.put("ImageName", "somefile");
imgupload.put("photo1", parseFile);
imgupload.saveInBackground();
```

So, your query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("photo");
query.whereEqualTo("ImageName", "somefile");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback <ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null){
            Log.d("USER", "OK");
        } else {
            Log.d("USER", "ex" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```